# I am getting /bin/sh: [npm: not found error while executing the react image in Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker

I have added Dockerfile in the react project and run this command `docker build . -t *image name*`.My build was success.But when I start to run my image (`docker run *imagename*`) I got this error `/bin/sh: [npm: not found`.I have attached my Dockerfile details below:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm" "start"]
```

Anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would revise the Dockerfile with the following:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Yes, if you use array syntax for `CMD` you have to put commas between arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else,

```
FROM node:15.13-alpine

WORKDIR /code/

#mapping environment path for node modules
ENV PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

COPY package.json yarn.lock /code/
# COPY package-lock.json /code/

RUN npm install

#adding the rest of the client code 
COPY . /code/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

All i had to do to solve this error was change the first line.
Change `WORKDIR /code/` to `/code`

The accepted answer covers it but it is easy to miss, as the answer mainly focuses on changing the last line which was not the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same isssue, then followed the [node js document](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) and updated my Dockerfile and problem resolved;

### Before:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

COPY . . 
RUN npm i

CMD ['npm', 'start']
```

---

### After:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . . 
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ['npm', 'start']

# or CMD ['node', 'server.js']
# both works
```